# How to get children for each internal node in R?

Tags: r, label, dendrogram, tree-nodes

For the dendrogram object how can I get children of the internal nodes? Ideally I would like to extract children with their labels.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The function `identify()` allows you to cut the tree and extract the children using the mouse. From ?identify.hclust:

```
  hca <- hclust(dist(USArrests))
  plot(hca)
  (x <- identify(hca))
```

Click the 2nd mouse button to terminate.